# What happens if I create a thread in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I want to create a thread in a asp.net mvc application.

What will happen?

A) Thread will die when request ends and the response is sent.

B) Thread will continue to run and response will be sent when thread terminates.

C) Thread will run without blocking the response and die when it have completed it's task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C.Thread will run without blocking respond and die when it is needed.

However, there are some pitfalls.  Threading can actually decrease performance if a large number of users are spawning threads.

If you haven't seen it already, here's an article covering threading in ASP.NET and explaining the pros and cons.

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Multithreading-Thread-Pool.aspx

Comment: Thank you, answer as i suspected :-)